# How to copy file to all subdirectories in tcsh

Tags: copy, tcsh, subdirectory

This question has been addressed for bash and other shells, but I can't seem to find an answer for TCSH shell.
So the title says it all, how can I copy a file that's in a directory to all its subdirectories in tcsh?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `tcsh` for-loop (which is a different syntax than a `bash` for-loop):

```
foreach f (*/)
cp $MYFILE $f
end
```

If file names or directory names may include white space, double-quote the variable expansion (i.e. `"$MYFILE"` and `"$f"`).